# Gstreamer 1.13.91 / 1.14.0 does not build on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm trying to build an android app with gstreamer. 
Gstreamer Version 1.12.3 and 1.12.4 are working quite fine but I can't compile
1.13.91 nor 1.14.0. 
Tried with ndk 12, 13, 15, and 16. 
There is always an error with the

```
android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold file '

Error:error: gstreamer-1.0-android-universal-1.13.91/arm64/lib/libcrypto.a(sha1-armv8.o): multiple definition of 'sha1_block_data_order
```

Same with gstreamer 14.0

Any ideas how to fix this?